# Cant make axios-mock-adpter work properly

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js13, axios-mock-adapter

I trying to implement the axios-mock-adpter just for mock (not unit test) while the backend do they work.

Im using Nextjs V.13,axios and axios-mock-adpter

1-AxiosMock and Mock Initializer

```
import axios from "axios";
import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";
export function createAxiosInstace() {
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
   baseURL: "http://localhost:3000",
 });
 return axiosInstance;
}

const mock = new MockAdapter(createAxiosInstace());
export default mock;
```

2-Make mock for a payment endpoint

```
import mock from "../axiosMock";

mock.onPost("/api/payments").reply(() => {
const paymentStatus = {
  id: "5e8891ab188cd28",
  status: "aproved",
  email: "jane@test.com",
  name: "Jane Doe",
 };
 return [200, { paymentStatus }];
});
```

3-Using a function the way we(workspace) use

```
import { createAxiosInstace } from "@/lib/axiosMock";

export async function sendPayment() {
 const response = await createAxiosInstace()
.post("/api/payments")
.then((response) => {
  return response;
})
.catch((error) => {
  return error;
});
 return response;
}
```

4-Get 404 error :)
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU5Rn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing, you are creating a new axios instance everytime, you need to create one, apply the mock to it, and then use this same instance. Also you need to specify the routes or use `mock.onAny` for example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/old-microservice-4gxxl4?file=/lib/axios.js

**mock.js**

```
import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";

export default function applyMockAdapter(axiosInstance) {
    const mock = new MockAdapter(axiosInstance);

    mock.onPost('/api/payments').reply(200, {
        status: "api/payments OK! "
    })

    mock.onAny().reply(200, {
        status: "Any other call will get this ",
        moreData: [1, 3, 4, 5,]
    })
}
```

**axios.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import applyMockAdapter from "./mock";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3000",
});

const someConfigToUseMock = true;

if (someConfigToUseMock) {
    applyMockAdapter(axiosInstance);
}

export default axiosInstance;
```

**page.js**

```
"use client";
import axiosInstance from '@/lib/axios'; // different name to avoid wrong import

export default function Home() {
  async function sendPayment() {
    const response = await axiosInstance // different name to avoid wrong import
      .post("/api/payments")
      .then((response) => {
        return response;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return error;
      });
    return response;
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={() => {
      sendPayment().then(console.log);
    }} >Make Request</button>
  )
}
```

**If you need to use a function you need the fuction to always return the same instance like this:**

```
import axios from "axios";
import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3000",
  });

export function createAxiosInstace() {
 return axiosInstance;
}

const mock = new MockAdapter(createAxiosInstace());
export default mock;
```

Comment: Vlw pela resposta detalhada
Porem continua dando 404

Comment: Alguma chance de você ter errado alguma config? sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-microservice-4gxxl4?file=/lib/axios.js

Comment: Se continuar 404 tenta fazer um sandbox com o erro

Comment: Ta ai:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/upbeat-panka-f8jvtm?file=%2F.codesandbox%2Ftasks.json%3A1%2C1
(Acho que estou deixando algo passar)

Comment: Vi o problema, eu coloquei o nome do custom axios de `axios` então fica fácil de importar o errado, eu troquei o nome: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/awesome-allen-cjdp4h?file=%2Fapp%2FraffleCalls.js%3A8%2C7

Comment: Aproveitando o contato, como que você fez para importar as dependencias nesse sandbox? eu tentei dele primerro e Não achei de jeito nenhum 

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente cara, vlw msm 

Sobre a segunda pergunta: Ue, ñ fiz nd de mais, so importei e deu certo kkkkk 